getQueryData always returns undefined even when set with useMutation - TanStack Query, React
When I try to read cache content of given key I receive undefined even after I call useMutation with exactly same key.
Mutation used to set cache (mutation returns proper data, as expected):
const axiosInstance = axios.create(habiticaAPIconf);

function parseResponse(response:LoginDataContract):AuthData{
  return {
    id: response.data.id,
    apiToken: response.data.apiToken,
    username: response.data.username
  }
}

const getAuthenticationData = async (userCredentials:UserCredentials):Promise<AuthData> => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.post<LoginDataContract>("/user/auth/local/login", {...userCredentials});
  return parseResponse(response.data);
}

export function useCredentialData() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (loginData:UserCredentials):Promise<AuthData> => getAuthenticationData(loginData),
    mutationKey: ['authData']
  });
};

Component used to fire the mutation:
export function LoginForm() {
  const { mutate, isSuccess, data } = useCredentialData();

  function handleLogin(e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mutate({
      username: (document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement).value,
      password: (document.getElementById("password") as HTMLInputElement).value
    });
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="email">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></input>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="password">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></input>
      </label>
      <button type="submit" onClick={ (e)=> {handleLogin(e)}}>Login</button>
      <span>{isSuccess ? `${data.username}` : ""}</span>
    </form>
  )
}

While clicking button in React Component undefined is always received even after abovementioned  mutatuion is called and returns proper data.
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export function SidebarTasksList() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return (
    <section>
      <button onClick={
        ()=>console.log(queryClient.getQueryData(['authData']))
      }>CLICK</button>
    </section>
  );

How to retrive data stored in ['AuthData'] cache? There is no function I could pass to useQuery as queryFn either, that's why I'm tring with getQueryData.

Generally speaking, mutations and queries have no correlation. Setting the same key on both of them does not achieve that they know about each other. The mutationKey is also optional. None of the examples actually set the key if I remember correctly because it's mostly used to share configuration between mutations.
What you need to do to "link" the result of your mutations to your queries is to either:

invalidate the query in response to the successful mutation. This is the path with the least code, as it will just re-fetch from the server:

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (loginData:UserCredentials):Promise<AuthData> => getAuthenticationData(loginData),
    onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['authData'])
  });


if your API call returns data, you can use that to manually write to the cache. This is more code, but one less round-trip to the server:

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (loginData:UserCredentials):Promise<AuthData> => getAuthenticationData(loginData),
    onSuccess: (data) => queryClient.setQueryData(['authData'], data)
  });


First proposition sounds very much like anitpattern, even if API I'm working with would not be returning data I would go with setQueryData, second approach worked perfectly thought.

Invalidation is very much recommend because it's the least amount of code and will always work even if you add code later. Trying to optimize for least amount of network requests seems a bit suboptimal

Ok, I think we missunderstood each other a bit. In API I'm working with the only way to receive credential data is with post call like I'm doing in getAuthenticationData  function. There is no useQuery definition nowhere in my code with key authData. In given case, if I understand correctly: invalidation will result either in cleaning authData cache or in nothing (because there is no queryFn assigned to authData). So now I'm thinking that rather than useMutation I should go with useQuery and pass post call as querFn there, do you think it's better approach?
